# Validation errors: how to get rid of "Validation failed: "?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

whenever I do

```
        rescue Exception => e
        flash[:error] = e.message
```

the e.message will always contain the "Validation error:" string and
the Object

Example:

Validation failed: Price "message:", Price "message"

How do I tell rails that I just want the message? and not the other
parts of the validation error to be displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the data you want from the `#errors` attribute of the model you were trying to save.  There could potentially be multiple validation errors (not just one).

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html